# How to aggregate skipped/ignored/null Items and expose them in the end of the job using Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

In spring batch I have a `tasklet` and a step (`reader`,`processor`,`writer`)
I am processing in chunks.

The `tasklet` downloads a file. the step is processing the lines in that file.

I added validation logic to the processor:

```
 @Override
    public MyObject process(MyOjbect item) throws Exception {
{
     ...
       boolean result=validateObject(item);
       if (result)
       {
          return item;
        }
       else
       {
          return null;
        }

}
```

My writer ignore nulls:

```
 public void write(List<? extends MyObject> items) throws Exception {
        for (MyObjectitem : items) {
            try {
                if (item != null) {
                    ....
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error writing item=" + item.toString(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The thing is that I want to calculate the number of Ignored/null items and expose it outside in the end of the job.

Any ideas how to do it?
I am going to have many jobs in parallel so multi-thread must be considered.

Thank you,
ray

This is how my processor is defined:

```
 @Bean
    public Step processSnidFileStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("processSnidFileStep")
                .<MyObject, MyObject>chunk(numOfProcessingChunksPerFile)
                .reader(reader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION,OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                .processor(asyncItemProcessor())
                .writer(asyncItemWriter())
                .listener(logProcessListener())
                .throttleLimit(20)
                .build();

    }


 @Bean
    public AsyncItemProcessor asyncItemProcessor() {
        AsyncItemProcessor<MyObject, MyObject> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(processor(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION,
                OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION,0));
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(infrastructureConfigurationConfig.taskProcessingExecutor());
        return asyncItemProcessor;

    }
```

Comment: Spring Batch exposes the number if items filtered in the job repository (`BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION.FILTER_COUNT`).  Is that not what you're looking for?  And for the record, item should never be null in an `ItemWriter` because if an `ItemProcessor` returns null, it is dropped as being filtered.

Comment: I guess thats what I am looking for.  but the value of that one is always zero (for all my jobs). and I know for sure that I got some "filtered" records which I return null. how that come?

Comment: And yes. I did get null itemes in my writer (while using chuncks). Any clue what's wrong ? I added additional code to my question

Comment: Here is a lead.. all nulls are actually being retrieved together with the populated objects within the ItemWriter item's list. what have I done wrong?

Comment: Ahhhh...just about everything I said breaks when using the asynchronous processor.

Comment: So I cant use asynchronous processor.. pff.. where was it written?:P driving me nuts. could you please elaborate this while answering this question? I will make it as answerd. thank you.

Comment: You can still use things like listeners to accomplish what you're looking for, it will just require a bit more code.  I'll elaborate in an answer.

Comment: Thanks. please mention also what if I do want to aggregate all those filtered records into a global verbal within the same job scope and expose it outside when the job finish to process. thank you again.

Comment: Hi Marin, I wonder if you had a chance to answer that one? we looking forward your response. thank you.

Comment: Martin, Sorry for pinging you again about this. Do you think you could answer that one any soon? Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm one thing before I create the answer, what version of Spring Batch are you using?

Comment: I missed that comment notification:(. I am using spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.3.RELEASE